# SSL handshake failed using wget, no error message from log

Tags: ssl

I am trying to `wget` a file from a https server using the command `wget -d --no-check-certificate https://abcde.com/test.tar.gz`

This is the log i obtained

```
Setting --check-certificate (checkcertificate) to 0
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.17.1 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /root/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2018-08-20 19:02:44--  https://abcde.com/test.tar.gz
Resolving proxy.png.mycompany.com (proxy.png.mycompany.com)... 172.xx.x.17x
Caching proxy.png.mycompany.com => 172.xx.x.17x
Connecting to proxy.png.mycompany.com (proxy.png.mycompany.com)|172.xx.x.17x|:911... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000560ce6ef84f0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
CONNECT abcde.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.17.1 (linux-gnu)
Host: abcde.com:443

---request end---
proxy responded with: [HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

]
Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake failed.
Closed fd 3
Unable to establish SSL connection.
Saving HSTS entries to /root/.wget-hsts
```

Comment: Might be some firewall/proxy blocking the connection, might be some misconfigured server, might be some mismatch in the capabilities between curl and the server, ...  - impossible to say based on these details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich forgot to mention this only happen when this command is inside a bash script and executed by ssh from another machine. I guess it might due to proxies, but i pretty sure the proxies were configured and it told from the logs too

Comment: It is a proxy according to the log. But it is not clear if this is the correct proxy and if the proxy allows access to the target or if there is some upstream firewall. Did you test access using exactly this proxy from this machine outside of SSH?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I ran this script and also this single command in the exact same machine with the same user which I ssh with, it executed without error. Proxies are set in the user's bashrc, and i did `source ./~bashrc` before i ran locally in the machine. This is kinda weird

Comment: Please compare the outputs of both scripts, especially what they show regarding use of a proxy.